# Laravel 5.6 Apply Middleware for controller certain methods

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.6 Apply Middleware for controller certain methods

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#controller-middleware

**without write a new class**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // how can apply this middleware for certain methods eg. store, update ?
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            // i need modify the $request->input('name')
            // before goes to method store, update

            // replace any space+ to a single space
            $request->merge(['name' => preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $request->input('name'))]);
            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

**Edited, this is not documented in the Laravel 5.6**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            // replace any space+ to a single space
            $request->merge(['name' => preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $request->input('name'))]);
            return $next($request);

        })->only(['store', 'update']);
    }
```

Comment: second argument to `middleware`, also builder methods to call after `middleware`

Comment: @lagbox i edited my question, is it correct/legit ? but it seems work LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

`$this->middleware('auth',['only' => ['store','update']]);
// Another Way
$this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['index','show']]);`

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/apply-middleware-for-certain-methods?page=0

Comment: but if without write a new middleware class, how can combine `$this->middleware(function ($request, $next)` and `$this->middleware('i dont need a new class')->only('store');`

Comment: You can use default 'auth' middleware

Comment: i edited my question, because i'm not use auth middleware, i need modify the $request->input('name') before the variable pass to method